# About the replaceWith function on a <div with id=

Tags: jquery

I have a HTML and javascript/ Jquery code which is divided into several div across the page. I am interested to use button functions and jquery to replace the DIV contents with each other or with different contents. So for example, in the code below, if I press the button with the id="DIV1", I want to replace the DIV with the id=#log2 contents with the DIV with the id=#log3.

```
At the moment it does not function like it should, when I press the button with the id="DIV1", the entire page including the positions of the DIV which were previously set in the STYLE sheet are replaced. So everything disappears, and I get only the content of the DIV with the id=#log3 placed at the top of the page, without using any style sheets. 

How can I fix this, because I want to replace the contents of the DIV with each other, or with new content, without losing the positions of the DIV across the page from STYLE sheet, or I want to place new content into the DIV without redefining its position on the page?


    <html>
    <head>
      <script>
        $function(){
           $("#DIV1").click(function() {
                 $("#log2").replaceWith("#log3");
                 $("#log3").replaceWith("");
                 $("#log6").replaceWith("");
           });
        }
      </script>
      <style type="text/css">

        #log2 {

          top: 15%;
          left: 1%;

        }

        #log3 {

          top: 15%;
          left: 10%;

        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
           <button type="button" id="DIV1" size="64">Button DIV1</button>

           <div id="log2" style="text-align:center; width: 13%; height:60%;">
                 <p> This is the first Text. </p>
           </div>

           <div id="log3" style="text-align:center; width: 13%; height:60%;">
                 <p> This is the second Text. </p>
           </div>



    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Something you should know

> The .replaceWith() method removes content from the DOM and inserts new
>   content in its place with a single call.

so in your code

```
$("#log2").replaceWith("#log3");
```

will replace

```
<div id="log2" style="text-align:center; width: 13%; height:60%;">
      <p> This is the first Text. </p>
</div>
```

with

```
<div id="log3" style="text-align:center; width: 13%; height:60%;">
    <p> This is the second Text. </p>
</div>
```

you maybe need to use `.html()` or `.insertAfter()`  or `.insertBefore()` like

```
$("#log2").html($("#log3").html());
```